# How i can add css transition to my Jquery dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my script for opening and closing dialog:

```
<script>
function open_dialog() {
    el = document.getElementById("dialog");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
}
</script>
```

This is my html code of dialog content:

```
<div id="dialog">
    <p>Dialog content</p>
</div>
```

And this is my css code:

```
#dialog {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 560px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 30%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -280px;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

So, how i can add transition to my dialog?

Comment: Check out [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions) resource. I suggest doing some research about transitions.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23492044/css-transition-not-working-on-dialog-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing it by setting a class on the element, instead of changing it's css properties with JavaScript.

```
#dialog {
    /* visibility: hidden; Remove this */
    .......

    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 1000ms;
}

#dialog.show {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Don't forget the rest of the browserprefixes for the `transition` property. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0wg0mz80/

Answer (score 0):

Use this `opacity`

```
#openDialog {
       opacity:0;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
-o-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
-webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
 width: 560px;
position: fixed;
top: 30%;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -280px;
height: 300px;
z-index: 999;
}
  <span id="dialog">open</span>
    <div id="openDialog">
        <p id='dialog'>Dialog content</p>
    </div>

    jQuery('#dialog').click(function(){
    $('#openDialog').css('opacity','1');
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/bJz7R/3/)